# How to extract Tags from XML into XLS using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xls

I have a utility that converts XML into XLS, I am able to extract actual data but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to dynamically extract tag names into column names.

I have XML something like this (but it could be any other XML with different name tags. I can extract ProjectXYZ, ABC and 12345678 into 3 columns in XLS, but I would like to also like to extract Title, Division, ID.

```
<ProjectDetails>
  <Project>
    <Title>ProjectXYZ</Title>
    <Division>ABC</Division>
    <ID>12345678</ID>
  </Project>
</ProjectDetails>
```

Comment: You might want to post some code that you already have working (in a minimal complete form): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What API do you use: streaming XmlReader, XmlDocument, XPathDocument, XDocument/XElement or something else?

Comment: You can use the DataSet ReadXml() method that will do everything automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head />
  <body title="Personnel">
    <p>
      <xsl:for-each select="ProjectDetails">
        <xsl:for-each select="Project">
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/> =
                  <xsl:for-each select="text()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </xsl:for-each>

               </li>
             </ul>
        </xsl:for-each></xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Seems to be what you are looking for, it returns the tag name and content

The result is:

- Title = ProjectXYZ
- Division = ABC
- ID = 12345678

Comment: `XLS` != `XSL`. OP using C#.